# How should I handle an edit review on a post I am going to flag for deletion

Tags: discussion, review, flags

Reviewing suggested edits showed this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22763288/which-is-the-best-tutorials-of-unity-3d-for-begginner#22763288 . The question asks for a tutorial and so is, I believe, not suitable for Stackoverflow. However the edit seemed reasonable.

I intend to flag the original question as a candidate for deletion. Should I think hard about an edit to this sort of edit? Should I just skip the edit? Should I (or how could I) reject the edit and say the editor should have flagged the question instead?

Answer (score 5):

I've been in this situation before to and I have even made my own edits to posts that were off-topic and most likely be closed. Afterwards, this seemed counter-productive.

1. If the edit is substantial enough that it could possibly help the
   question to not be closed then I would approve it.
2. If, as in this case, the question can't be helped without being completely rewritten and to ask a whole new question then I wouldn't reject the edit but just skip it. Hopefully others would do the same and the suggested edit would die with the question. Maybe someone can help out on that as I don't know but logic dictates that the suggested edit would be removed from the queue if the question is deleted.

If the question is deleted then the member who suggested the edit would lose those 2 points anyway so skipping then flagging the question as you intend to do seems appropriate to me.