# Dealing with suggested edits on question to be closed as duplicate

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

There is a question on one of the SE sites that had a pending suggested edit: trust me, the way the original question was, it was needed. Before I even thought to approve the edit, I went to close it as a duplicate (as it was), but the suggested edit was still there.

**If the question is being closed anyways** (as a duplicate or otherwise) **do I reject or approve the suggested edit? What is the proper etiquette?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How should I handle an edit review on a post I am going to flag for deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227320/how-should-i-handle-an-edit-review-on-a-post-i-am-going-to-flag-for-deletion)

Comment: @codeMagic No, this is not about posts that are intended to be deleted.

Comment: @Gilles you're right, I jumped the gun on that one. I guess I should have just said related and not flagged because part of the answer would fit. That's what I get for trying to post while brushing my unicorn. I will pay more attention.

Comment: @codeMagic As retribution, upvotes to all of us!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Treat it like you would any other suggested edit: if it improves the question, approve it, and if it changes the meaning of its content, or makes it worse, reject it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns

Answer (score 5):

Questions closed as duplicates generally stay around to act as searching sign-posts. They are not automatically deleted, as a rule.

If the edit is useful and improves the post, approve it.